# How to push to a folder within a folder on a private Git Repo

Tags: git, github

There's a repo that I was granted access to so it's not my own.

I only want to push changes to a folder within a folder:

PrivateRepo/folder1/folder2

I've got my local git all setup ready to push,

I set my origin as the URL leading to 'folder2' (I've removed private information but in my master I'm using a proper URL:

https://github.com/[group]/[privateRepo]/tree/master/[folder1]/[folder2]

But I get an error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/[group]/[privateRepo]/tree/master/[folder1]/[folder2]' not found
```

So how can I add my local folder files and sub folders into the private repo's sub folders?

Comment: I dont follow your question, the error doesnt really seem to follow what youre trying to do. If you want to push only specific subdirectories use "git add <dir name>" then commit and push that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repositories only work as a *whole*. Since Git tracks the full contents of the working directory as a single unit, you can only push to the full repository, not to a subfolder of your project.

So to make this work, you will still have to clone the full repository, and work with the full project. It then comes down to your “discipline” to only edit files within that one subfolder if that’s required.

Comment: I see, so if I setup my local folder like this `[myFolder]/[folder1]/[folder2]/` and then set my origin to `https://github.com/[group]/[privateRepo]/` then I can just push the files within my own system or do I still need to clone the whole repo?

Comment: Git will require you to clone the repository before you can contribute to it. So starting with a fresh directory will not work. Why don’t you create a new repository for your work instead?

Comment: thanks for your help, it's a team project and I only work on this particular sub-directory of files, I'm new to the whole thing so I thought I could just push my files directly into a sub-directory, I'll do the cloning like you advise though since that's the only way to do it